# Permutation with different target vector?

Tags: r, permutation

I'd like to know if there's a function or optimal way to generate all possible permutations when target vector is different for each element. Here's my example:
First and third element from (a,b,c), and second one from (a,b,c,d). I'd like to have permutations of length 3 (36 of them):

```
aaa, aab, aac, aad
aba, aca, baa, caa
bab, bac, bad, cab
cac, cad, cba, cbb,
cbc, cbd, cca, ccb,
```

.
.
.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `expand.grid()` like so:

```
v1 <- c("a","b","c")
v2 <- v1
v3 <- v1
```

`vFull <- expand.grid(v1,v2,v3)`

Comment: Thanks a lot . I 'd check both methods to see which one is faster when 3 changes to 10-12.

Comment: Thanks Mako212. This method is  faster!

Answer (score 1):

You can use merge with no `by` parameter to make all possible combos.

```
v1 <- c("a","b","c")
v2 <- c("a","b","c", "d")
perm <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by =NULL), list(v1, v2, v1))
perm
# x y.x y.y
# 1  a   a   a
# 2  b   a   a
# 3  c   a   a
# 4  a   b   a
# 5  b   b   a
# 6  c   b   a
# 7  a   c   a
# 8  b   c   a
# 9  c   c   a
# 10 a   d   a
# 11 b   d   a
# 12 c   d   a
# 13 a   a   b
# 14 b   a   b
# 15 c   a   b
# 16 a   b   b
# 17 b   b   b
# 18 c   b   b
# 19 a   c   b
# 20 b   c   b
# 21 c   c   b
# 22 a   d   b
# 23 b   d   b
# 24 c   d   b
# 25 a   a   c
# 26 b   a   c
# 27 c   a   c
# 28 a   b   c
# 29 b   b   c
# 30 c   b   c
# 31 a   c   c
# 32 b   c   c
# 33 c   c   c
# 34 a   d   c
# 35 b   d   c
# 36 c   d   c
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! How can I change it to return permutations of length 2 and 1?
These merge and by were always a mystery for me!
I was more thinking of permutations and lapply, as my return values or of different length if I want to generate all permutations, but permutations doesn't work for different target vector.

Comment: Do you want to permute 2 vectors or retrieve the first two characters of the above permutation?

Comment: Actually it's perfectly fine! my vectors were c("0","1","2") and ("0","1","2,"3"), and I got confused.
Thank a lot emilliman5!

Comment: subset the matrix as follows: `perm[, 1:2]` or `perm[, 1]`. NB: I edited my answer to assign the permuations to `perm`